# Loading indicator for xeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using X-Editable (earlier Bootstrap-Editable) for in-place editing.
While saving data on server takes approximately 2-3 seconds.
Meanwhile this time span, i want to put a loading indicator.
How do i implement this?

Answer (score -1):

call an ajaxfunction to update contains the loading icon, like the function below:

```
function ajaxUpdate()
{
    var def = '<img src="./images/loader.gif" />';
    $('#loading').html(def);
    $('#loading').show();
    jQuery.post("<?php echo site_url('myController/updateDetails');?>", {
      v1 : $('#v1').text(),
      v2 : $('#v1').text(),
      v3 : $('#v1').text()
    },
    function(response)
    {
       if(response==1)
       {
          //success area
          $('#loading').hide();
       }
       else
       {
          // failure area
       }
    });
}
```

---

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

when calling this function the loading image is displayed on the div with id **loading**
and after success of the ajax call it will be hidden.